# Android app crashes when touched outside the ImageView

Tags: java, android

When i touched the ImageView it display the color from the image but when i touched outside the image the app crashes.

Here's my xml code:

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/colorimage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:src="@drawable/color" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/displaycolor"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/colorimage"/>
```

And here is the main code:

```
 mImageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    mImageView.buildDrawingCache(true);

    mImageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
                Bitmap bitmap = mImageView.getDrawingCache();

               int pixel = bitmap.getPixel((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY());

                int r = Color.red(pixel);
                int g = Color.green(pixel);
                int b = Color.blue(pixel);

                display.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(r , g , b));

            }

            return true;
        }
    });
```

Logcat error message:
[Error Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nbQm.png)

Comment: Post you error logs.

Comment: For us to better understand where the problem is you need to provide Logcat error message.

Comment: Also, please advise which line is line 84 of `CropImageGalleryActivity.java`

Comment: If your code is from `CropImageGalleryActivity.java`,  the problem seems coming from that line `int pixel = bitmap.getPixel((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY());`. It seems that the second argument `(int)event.getY()` is <0 although it should be >=0.

Comment: you can share CropImageGalleryActivity class

Answer (score 0):

Change the line `if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)` to :

```
if(v.getId() == R.id.colorimage){
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
       {........}
}
```

The on touch listener has been set to the whole activity not a particular view and the bitmap operation cannot be done on the other views except this one so the view so it is crashing.

Comment: This is line 84 :  int pixel = bitmap.getPixel((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY());

Comment: Reffer to the comment by Maxouille

Comment: But how would I declare y >=0?